# What resistor values should I use for a voltage divider that has to operate at low temperatures?

Tags: resistors, temperature, voltage-divider

I'm designing a flight computer for a lightweight pico balloon - it will (hopefully) operate in the upper atmosphere down to around -40C. To keep the weight down, the whole thing is going to be operated off 1 AA battery with a charge pump. However, when reading [the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/25173A.pdf) for the chosen charge pump (MCP16251), I spotted something I hadn't taken into consideration:

> When an application runs below -20C, smaller values for feedback resistors should be used to avoid any alteration of VOUT, because of the leakage path on PCBs. (Page 12, section 4.2.3.)

Choosing smaller resistor values is trivial, but I'm unsure of exactly what's happening here (why it's affected by temperature), and just how much smaller values I should choose than the examples they give in the datasheet (in the order of 1MOhm.)

Comment: Without a schematic (and since this is about leakage paths on a pcb, the pcb layout) there can't be said much. If the leakage path is long enough and/or the thing is properly conformally coated that note is zilch anyways.

Comment: @PlasmaHH No schematic yet as I'm just researching components - but how is it that temperature affects the leakage path, in either case?

Comment: One thing could be that depending on the contaminants that cause the leakage, they might drastically decrease the resistance.

Comment: Page 12, section 4.2.3

Comment: @placeholder Sorry - should have added that to the quote.

Comment: Leakages in the IC will be worst at higher temperatures; at low temperatures you'd worry about moisture condensing on the PCB causing leakage. If the environment of the balloon has low humidity, this may not actually be a problem. In the end, leakage will affect accuracy of the output voltage setting. For an estimate, consider that you may get 100Mohm leakage between nodes -- you can then estimate if that is significant to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statements in the datasheet do **not** seem to be related as you appear to have assumed. Leakage paths are not associated with low temperatures, there are two separate issues. Edit: Noted that the OP quoted a different section of the datasheet which appears (to me) to be wrong.

At lower temperatures, the gain of BJTs will drop so the error due to bias currents will be higher, hence you should use lower value resistors for the same accuracy level. The feedback bias current is **typically** 10nA at 25°C, which is consistent with a BJT input.

It's not clear from the datasheet what the internal circuitry is- but the 1.23V implies a bipolar bandgap reference and they may have a BJT-input differential amplifier for the error amplifier- they say transconductance type, which is typically bipolar input.

Actual datasheet text:

[image]

This is really a common issue when you are designing products that have to operate over a wide temperature range- some things tend to deteriorate at low temperatures, and some at high temperatures (and many things get worse with radiation, but that's another story).

Comment: The datasheet extract I quoted definitely says "*because* of the leakage path on PCBs", so I'd say it made the relation quite explicit! This was part of my confusion, as I also didn't see the correlation between temperature and leakage paths. I had no idea about the gain of BJTs dropping with temperature decreases either though so thanks for that - interesting to note!

Comment: @berry120 Ah, yes, I wonder if someone re-wrote that part of the datasheet to 'clarify' without knowledge of the actual issues. Ugh.

Comment: @SpheroPefhany Quite possibly - for better or worse, I've just always had it bashed into me that the datasheet is never wrong :)

Comment: @berry120 Unfortunately, datasheets are wrong from time to time- and all but the most straightforward example circuits are often enough unsuitable for real use, especially in the analog world. Suspicion is justified.  When they are not wrong they are sometimes written deliberately to hide  bad things like the LT1028 original datasheet omitting a huge spike in the noise PSD graph by stopping at a lower frequency.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Written like a man who has been bitten! I had to switch from LT1028 to OPA211 late in the day. Getting a full frequency graph out of LT was like drawing teeth.

Answer (score 2):

In general, inside the chip, there isn't really any highly dominant effect that would cause this, so the effect should be small.  Except for one case ... at lower temperatures you tend to have moisture condensation on the board that then will cause all sorts of weirdness and leakage paths.  For high value resistors (1 MOhm +) this could be problematic.

I suggest two things:
1) encapsulate your board,
2) test at these lower temperatures using dry ice,

I certainly can understand keeping the resistor values high as every uA is important in an application like this.